# Excel Identifying biggest drop in a number series / on a graph

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a running total figure in a single column that gradually increases over time but fluctuates along the way.

I am trying to identify the largest negative downturn in the series as an absolute number.  In other words, what is the biggest decline experienced and from what point to what point along the way.

Is this possible either on a graph or to derive it from the series of numbers.  Example of what I am talking about. In my series, the biggest downturn is between the 61st number (43.95) and 102nd number (25.70) so the answer I am looking for is 18.25.

I need to do this in a column of 4000+ numbers in the series.

Is this possible without VBA?

Comment: Something like this?  http://www.peltiertech.com/highlight-min-and-max-data-points-in-an-excel-chart

Comment: No unfortunately not as that gives the lowest and highest values on the graph. My graph oscillates up and down over time but the general trend is a steady incline. I am trying to identify the largest "downturn" within the overall range.

Comment: To clarify, by "largest downturn" or "biggest decline", you mean from a peak, after which there is no higher value before eventually bottoming out, to the lowest subsequent point regardless of intermediate activity, based on raw values and with no time constraints?  For example, say your data also contains these values: after the 102nd number, values oscillate but generally rise and by the 1,000th value is back up to 43.00.  The 1,005th value is 18.00.  Would the decline of interest be 43.95 to 18.00 or 43.00 to 18.00?  When would the decline be deemed to start in such a case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do find the amount of the greatest decline using a helper column. For values in `A2:A4000`, enter the following in `B2` and fill down the column:

```
=MAX(A$2:A2)-A2
```

This formula will return the greatest decline represented by the current value. All you need to do to find the greatest decline in the data set is to find the max value in column B.

```
=MAX(B2:B4000)
```

*Example:*

[image]

Comment: Cheers Excellll - also perfect and does exactly what I need too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate it with two helper columns:

- first column to get the address of the smallest number after the actual one: `="B"&ROW(OFFSET(B2,MATCH(MIN(B3:$B$26),B3:$B$26,0),0))`
- second column is to calculate this difference: `=B2-INDIRECT(C2)` (don't enter it in the last cell otherwise it might give you wrong result)

Note: in my solution I use that highest downturn is always end at the minimum of the range between start position and end of data

Now you just need to filter for the highest value and you will see also the other end of the range in the address column.

(e.g. in attached picture biggest downturn is 20, from rows 3 to 7).
[image]

Comment: Perfect Máté - does exactly what I needed.  Thanks very much! Nick